# Are OEM's retaining Synaptics driver for linux?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptic

On their website, Synaptics states that they delivers their linux driver to OEM when they buy Synaptics product :

> SGS-L is provided free of charge to Synaptics OEM/ODM partners when ordered with Synaptics TouchPad and ClickPad™ products.

http://www.synaptics.com/en/gesture-suite-linux.php

It's advertised as the same as the windows driver. So should I call Lenovo/HP/Dell to get my fully working touchpad driver in linux ?

Comment: You don't need to contact them. There is a deb package somewhere that has the touchpad driver.

Comment: You mean `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` ? But this driver is open-source and unfortunatly uncomplete. I'm searching why Synaptics can claim they have a fully working linux driver without anybody seeing any of it.

Comment: So they have it but we can't see it right? Any reason why? Apart Microsoft forbidding it?

Comment: Also, bottom of [this](http://www.synaptics.com/en/tips.php) page.

Comment: I saw a rpm floating around... but it won't install proper on ubuntu. so yeah, they say they "have it" but i doubt it works in any proper fashion until a OEM wants to pay them money to make it work...